# Oracle APex calculate profit on rendering

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I have an interactive grid with fixed rows and need to calculate the formula on pre-rendering.

So the source query is:

```
select kpi,monthly,yearly from kpi where project_id = :P1_PROJECT_ID;
```

I need to modify this so that the row where kpi='Gross' is calculated on rendering.

[image]

It looks in the grid like:

[image]

Expected result:(Gross=Profit/Loss)
[image]

I am trying to write sql query but it doesn;t work.
Despite data it returns null.
What am i doing wrong here?

```
 select kpi,
case when KPI='Gross'
then to_char(case when KPI='Profit' then to_number(replace(nvl(monthly,0),',','')) end /
case when KPI='Loss' then to_number(replace(nvl(monthly,0),',','')) end ,'999,999,999,999') 
else to_char( monthly,'999,999,999,999') end as monthly,
case when KPI='Gross'
then to_char(case when KPI='Profit' then to_number(replace(nvl(yearly,0),',','')) end /
case when KPI='Loss' then to_number(replace(nvl(yearly,0),',','')) end ,'999,999,999,999')  
else to_char( yearly,'999,999,999,999') end as yearly,
from kpi where project_id = :P1_PROJECT_ID;
```

To_char is used to display values as comma separated.
So it would when KPI=Gross, it will divide the columns where kpi=profit by kpi=Loss and dispaly result.

Also the result in the row where KPI=Gros should also have % concatenated.

Apex 20.2

How can this be achieved?

Comment: It is not clear what your results would look like.  That information should be in the question.

Comment: I have updated OP with the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, but you need to use window functions. Without using window functions,  the query will not look at the other rows in the case statements to calculate the GROSS column.

The query below is how to properly calculate the GROSS using window functions. I have added `ROUND` to round the gross to an integer, but you can remove that if you want the decimal points.

```sql
WITH
    kpi (pk,
         kpi,
         monthly,
         yearly,
         project_id)
    AS
        (SELECT 1, 'Revenue', 60000, 2000000, 1 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 'Profit', 20, 30, 1 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, 'Loss', 10, 50, 1 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 4, 'Gross', NULL, NULL, 1 FROM DUAL)
SELECT k.kpi,
       CASE k.kpi
           WHEN 'Gross'
           THEN
                  ROUND (
                        SUM (CASE k.kpi WHEN 'Profit' THEN k.monthly ELSE 0 END)
                            OVER (PARTITION BY project_id)
                      / SUM (CASE k.kpi WHEN 'Loss' THEN k.monthly ELSE 0 END)
                            OVER (PARTITION BY project_id))
               || '%'
           ELSE
               TO_CHAR (k.monthly)
       END    AS monthly,
       CASE k.kpi
           WHEN 'Gross'
           THEN
                  ROUND (
                        SUM (CASE k.kpi WHEN 'Profit' THEN k.yearly ELSE 0 END)
                            OVER (PARTITION BY project_id)
                      / SUM (CASE k.kpi WHEN 'Loss' THEN k.yearly ELSE 0 END)
                            OVER (PARTITION BY project_id))
               || '%'
           ELSE
               TO_CHAR (k.yearly)
       END    AS yearly
  FROM kpi k
 WHERE project_id = 1;
```

```
       KPI    MONTHLY     YEARLY
__________ __________ __________
Revenue    60000      2000000
Profit     20         30
Loss       10         50
Gross      2%         1%
```